# Input text field(mobile app) which does not allow user to Enter Numeric value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

```
<input type="text"  
       ng-model="emp.eedKey007" 
       ng-keypress="nonNumericInput($event)" >
```

input text field of mobile app(app is  using ionic and angularjs ) which is mapped with the $scope.emp.eedKey007 in controller.
I want to make this text field non-numeric. if user want to insert any numeric value  he will not able to enter in **text Field(MOBILE)**

```
$scope.nonNumericInput = function ($event) {
    console.log("key presed");
    $scope.showFixAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: $translate('Info'),
            template: $translate('Invalid Input ...')
        });
    };
    var charCode = $event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {  
        console.log("Character is pressed"); 
    } else {
        $scope.showFixAlert();
        /**/ what code should i need to use here so that i can restrict numeric value inserted in text field.** 
       // in below code i try to replace the numeric  character with blank character. which is assigned in eedKey007 but its not working correctly . I can't blank the textfield on numeric value insertion.
        var StringLang = $scope.emp.eedKey007;
        $scope.emp.eedKey007 = StringLang.replace(StringLang.slice(-1),''); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $event.preventDefault(); in your else case. It will prevent entering the numeric value to input box.